# texture painting now showing up (and bugs explanation?)

Tags: rendering, texture-painting, error, mirror

i'm a complete beginner in blender. i've made a face using automirror but then texture paint were behaving weirdly. i disabled it and then used the mirror modifier on the mesh, but then the texture paint were working only on a half of the mesh (on solid view only the right side were painted, while on other modes it was the left side).

i then realized i didn't enable clipping while using the modifier, so i erased half of the mesh and made all again.. and then the painting got much weirder. when i painted on the backside the pattern apeared on the front side and vice versa.

i don't know what i did after that (maybe it worked when i tried flipping the normals) but now i tried again and it's finally painting coreclty, but the painting isn't showing on rendering and material preview modes (i linked the material to the uv image but nothing)

any clues of what happened so i don't commit the same mistake again (cause i really don't know what i did)? and why isn't showing up on other modes?

[image: solid mode] [image: rendering mode]

blender file: [image]

Comment: Please upload your Blend file (with materials packed (via File > External Data > Pack Resources)  so that we can see what's going on. Follow the instructions [here](https://blend-exchange.com/help).

Comment: @JohnEason just uploaded!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to look at your file closely tonight as it's approaching 1am here. However, it looks as if the head has somehow been rotated 180 degrees. If you press 1 on the numpad it should show the front of the head, but it's actually showing the back! For some reason the UV unwrap of the face is offset too although the object itself seems to be symetrical.

Comment: @JohnEason wow, i really don't know what i've done, i got really confused, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the second material to your head, but you need to assign the first one. Select the face, switch to *Edit* mode, select all and click *Assign*:

[image]

Note that in the *Material* panel, under *Viewport Display*, you've chosen a pink color, so the head will appear pink and not grey when you'll be in *Solid* mode. Now you'll be able to see the texture and to paint on it when you'll switch to *Texture Paint* mode.

As for why, in *Solid* mode, you see the texture while it is not even assigned to the object, it's a bit confusing but it has to do with the image that is selected in the *N panel > Tool > Texture Slot*. If you stay in *Single Image* mode you'll see the selected image texture, if you switch to *Material* instead of *Single Image* you'll see the assigned material:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! it worked!